# Parametrized left join in Rails 7 - select records that are null or true

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

This code doesnt do what I want:

```
joins(
  'LEFT OUTER JOIN cats ON owners.id = cats.owner_id AND "cats"."hungry" IS FALSE'
).where(
  'cats.hungry IS FALSE OR cats.hungry IS NULL'
)
```

There are 3 owner records: A, B & C

There are two cat records: Cat-A (hungry), Cat-B (not-hungry)

I want to segment my owners into 2 groups:

I want owners with:

1.) Owners with cats that ARE hungry.
2.) No cat linked (ie cats.hungry IS NULL) - or linked cat that is not hungry

1.) Owner-A has a hungry cat: cat-A

2.) Owner-B's cat is not hungry (cat-B) & Owner-C has no cat.

I thought the left-join above would get me - cats where there is a join but only joins where the cat is NOT hungry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the second ON condition, so that evety owner with or without cat is present, and only the where lause decides which rows must be removed

```
joins(
  'LEFT OUTER JOIN cats ON owners.id = cats.owner_id'
).where(
  'cats.hungry IS FALSE OR cats.hungry IS NULL'
)
```